# Syntax error in MySQL cursor loop

Tags: mysql, database, cursor, syntax-error

I'm having an issue looping through the results of a query with a cursor. My goal generate a JSON array using the results. I'm using MySQL 5.6.20 on Fedora.

My code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_quotes_for_customer;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `get_quotes_for_customer`(c CHAR(6)) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE qcur CURSOR FOR SELECT id, submit_date FROM quote_forms WHERE owner=c;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    OPEN qcur;

    SET @output = '[';
    t: LOOP
      FETCH qcur INTO @i, @t;
      IF done=1 THEN
        LEAVE t;
      END IF;
      SET @newrow = concat('{"id": "', @i, '", "timestamp": "', @t, '"}');
      SET @output = concat_ws(@output, @newrow);
    END LOOP;
    SET @output = concat(@output, ']');

    RETURN @output;
  END;
```

And the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@i, @t;
  IF done=1 THEN
    LEAVE t;
  END IF;
  SET @newrow = ' at line 12
```

What could be the problem here? I've been wracking my brain for several hours now, and the error messages aren't very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Change the [9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) `@i` and `@t` for [13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html) `i` and `t`.

Comment: that fixed it - add it as an answer and I'll accept it.